# Como me posso proteger de servidores proxy?

Tags: php

Bom é o seguinte, eu estou fazendo um site onde pago por cada visita ao usuário que ele consiga.

Contudo existe alguma forma de saber se determinado IP é um proxy ou não, ou seja existe alguma forma de saber se aquele usuário está a usar VPN ou não? E se existe, como posso bloquear o usuário de usar proxy?

Obrigado.

Comment: Talvez isso lhe ajude: https://medium.com/@ValdikSS/detecting-vpn-and-its-configuration-and-proxy-users-on-the-server-side-1bcc59742413#.rmi42s248

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não tem como se defender de maneira eficiente e VPN é impossível (até aonde entendo), a única maneira seria tendo uma lista de IPs que seja fornecida por algum serviço, no entanto isto não é bem um caso de programação necessariamente, desconheço qualquer tipo de serviço que forneça estas listas, mas o caminho é este provavelmente.

No entanto alguns proxies repassam dados no HTTP, o que pode ajudar a verificar isto, não encontrei muitos detalhes dos headers, pois nem todos são padronizados, no entanto esta conversa no wikipedia tenta dar ou obter alguma orientação: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AX-Forwarded-For, segue alguns detalhes:

O [header "Via"](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.45) que é usado por gateways e proxies para indicar os protocolos intermediários e destinatários entre o "user agent" e o servidor sobre os pedidos, e entre o servidor de origem e o cliente nas respostas, uso no PHP:

- `HTTP_VIA`

Detalhes sobre `Forwarded:` https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239#section-5.2, uso no PHP:

- `HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR`
- `HTTP_FORWARDED`
- `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` (provavelmente era usado antes do `HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR`, quando ainda era experimental)
- `HTTP_X_FORWARDED` (provavelmente era usado antes do `HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR`, quando ainda era experimental)

O `X-Cluster-Client-IP:` que aparentemente é exigido pelos servidores de web Zeus:

- `HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP`

O `Client-IP:` eu não consegui encontrar informação alguma, o que me parece é que ele era usado antes do `Forwarded:`, uso no PHP:

- `HTTP_CLIENT_IP`
- `HTTP_X_CLIENT_IP` (variação do `HTTP_CLIENT_IP`)

### Detectando se esta usando um proxy que passa cabeçalho(s)

No PHP ficaria algo como:

```
<?php
function isProxy()
{
    $proxyTypes = array(
        'HTTP_VIA',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED',
        'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP',
        'HTTP_CLIENT_IP',
        'HTTP_X_CLIENT_IP'
    );

    foreach ($proxyType as $proxyTypes) {
          if (!empty($proxyType)) {
              return true;
          }
    }

    return false;
}

if (isProxy()) {
    //Finaliza o script PHP e emite uma mensagem, pode customizar essa if como desejar
    die('Você está usando proxy');
}
```

### Detectando se esta usando um web-proxy:

Os web-proxies geralmente usam frames, então é possivel fazer apenas a checagem se a sua página está rodando dentro de um `<iframe>` ou `<frame>`, adicione assim no rodapé da página:

```
<script>
function detectLoadInFrame()
{
    //O try previne problemas de bloqueios de CORS
    try {
        if (window.self !== window.top) {
              window.top.location = window.location;
        }
    } catch (e) {
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Porém note que as vezes os web-proxies bloqueiam o Javascript, isto faz com que tenha problemas ao fazer a detecção, então o interessante seria bloquear alguma funcionalidade HTML principal, como o navbar, ou um form, por exemplo:

estilo.css:

```
.navbar {
    display: none;
}

.navbar.show {
    display: block;
}
```

Seu html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar">
           <a href="...">...</a>
        </nav>

        <form id="meuform">
           <input type="text" disabled>
           <select disabled></select>
        </form>

        <script>
        function detectLoadInFrame()
        {
            //O try previne problemas de bloqueios de CORS
            try {
                if (window.self !== window.top) {
                      window.top.location = window.location;
                } else {
                    //Exibe o navbar
                    document.querySelector(".navbar").className += " show";

                    //Habilita os campos
                    var fields = document.querySelectorAll("#meuform [disabled]");

                        for (var i = fields.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            fields[i].disabled = false;
                        }
                }
            } catch (e) {
            }
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esta será a forma mais eficas de se prevenir de um proxy ou de uma vpn?

Comment: @Gonçalo acho que não entendeu no começo da resposta, eu disse: Não tem como se defender de maneira eficiente e VPN é impossível. Ou seja é somente pra proxy, é só eficiente se o proxy passar os dados, caso contrário também é impossivel, estou editando a resposta pra mais detalhes ;)

Comment: Cara, impossivel não é, o 4chan consegue descobrir quando alguém está usando VPN, agora é bem díficil.

Comment: @RaphaelCaldas eu não sei como eles fazem, mas eu suponho que os serviços de VPN usem caminhos de gateway, o que poderia ser verificado no nivel da máquina/equipamento, mas a nivel de linguagem de programação direcionada a web acho que não é possivel

Comment: @Gonçalo editei, inclusive a introdução da resposta, espero que ajude, se eu encontrar algum serviço do tipo lhe informo.

Comment: Obrigado, vou experimentar! Se der para prevenir proxys é melhor, além disso, vou fazer outros sistemas em PHP, para criar uma "sequencia" de tempo, e se a sequencia for muito semelhante, o usuário é bloqueado. Sempre previne!

Comment: Experimentei com um proxy do hidemyass e o PHP não funciou, não mostrou a mensagem de proxy...

Comment: @Gonçalo hidemyass não é Proxy é WebProxy, são duas coisas diferentes, foi por isto que eu adicione um exemplo com webproxy aonde escrevi "Detectando se esta usando um web-proxy". Webproxies não enviam headers e nem todos proxies enviarão headers também. No entanto estas são as maneiras mais eficientes que encontrei (já usei ambas no site de alguns clientes).

Comment: Diga-me uma coisa, no segundo caso do WebProxy, a unica alternativa é Usar JS? é que no caso eu estou a usar um ficheiro PHP.

Comment: @Gonçalo Sim proxies normais que enviam headers a solução é PHP, já webproxies a solução é somente com javascript, ou seja combine ambas e terá uma razoável solução ;)

Answer (score -1):

Até onde eu sei se o usuário não envia alguns headers vc não tem como detectar, porem se o user envia um `X-FORWARDED-FOR` ai voce pode tentar filtrar. Mas voce tem que aceitar que alguns vao passar.Pois muitos proxies sao anonimos.